# Is possible to allows cors access from one domain only in php

Tags: php

I am created a PHP RESP API application. I need to access this application from another domain using its API. Is it possible to specify cors domain in Header

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
 ...
```

The above code allows cors from every domain.But i need to allow cors from a specific domain only.

Comment: then instead of "*" you should specify the domain.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header controls what a given page can sent requests to except the original one. So it controls the "to", not the "from". You need to specify such header not inside your API, but in the page making the requests to that API.

Answer (score 5):

**try below code:**

```
<?php
// Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Header
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://base.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your immediate question, but personally I use the below to make sure content gets out only if on the proper host.

```
$host = 'example.com';

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $host) {
  header("Location: http://$host");
  exit;
}
```

In .htaccess I set `Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"` to further limit access.

Answer (score -2):

The solution to this issue is to use the $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] variable to determine whether the request has come from an allowed domain. It has then set this:

**try below code:**

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` can be spoofed.